manipulating a json file
Hi I would like to consult on any ideas on how I can manipulate a json file via linux command line by swapping the Weight values (0 and 100) of 2 objects.
From This:
[
  {
    "Type": "forward",
    "ForwardConfig": {
      "TargetGroups": [
        {
          "TargetGroupArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:123456789:targetgroup/Pogi-Clust-MABAHOUTOT/0887654321",
          "Weight": "100"
        },
        {
          "TargetGroupArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:123456789:targetgroup/Pogi-Clust-UTOMABAHO/1234567890",
          "Weight": "0"
        }
      ],
      "TargetGroupStickinessConfig": {
        "Enabled": false
      }
    }
  }
]

To This:
[
      {
        "Type": "forward",
        "ForwardConfig": {
          "TargetGroups": [
            {
              "TargetGroupArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:123456789:targetgroup/Pogi-Clust-MABAHOUTOT/0887654321",
              "Weight": "0"
            },
            {
              "TargetGroupArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:123456789:targetgroup/Pogi-Clust-UTOMABAHO/1234567890",
              "Weight": "100"
            }
          ],
          "TargetGroupStickinessConfig": {
            "Enabled": false
          }
        }
      }
    ]

 


jq is quite a convenient tool for manipulating json files from the command line

smth like jq '.[0].ForwardConfig.TargetGroups[0].Weight as $t0 | .[0].ForwardConfig.TargetGroups[0].Weight=.[0].ForwardConfig.TargetGroups[1].Weight | .[0].ForwardConfig.TargetGroups[1].Weight=$t0'

@yvs2014 solution worked on me, I just need to forward the output to a new json file
